# Best way to connect per-thread streams to separate processes

Tags: multithreading, bash, io, process-substitution

I have a single compute intensive process X that is parallelised using threads
across multiple CPUs.  Each thread produces stream output, and each stream
should be connected separately to its own instance of a second process Y (there
will be as many processes Y running as there are threads).
X and Y respectively write and read a binary format so that throughput is quite good.
I would like to minimise any I/O overhead and am looking for the best way to do so.
At the moment my setup looks like this (illustrated with just two threads, but typically I would have more than eight):

```
exec 4> >( programY > out.4 )
exec 5> >( programY > out.5 )

programX-that-writes-to-fd-4-and-5

exec 4>&-
exec 5>&-
```

One issue is that the bash manual states: "Redirections using file descriptors greater than 9 should be used with care, as they may conflict with file descriptors the shell uses internally." This is not exactly clear. Another issue is that I have not found a good way to establish termination: At the moment I use "lsof -c programY", but that feels like a hack. Is there a better or improved solution? The 'given' here is that X is multi-threaded and compute intensive, Y is single-threaded and compute intensive, and that each thread of X has to be hooked up to an instance of Y.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably design program `X` so that it could be told how many child processes to launch and give it a template (effectively a `printf()` format string) for how to create those processes:

```
alt-X -n 100 -f "Y > out.%d"
```

and leave it to deal with the file descriptors etc.

However, failing that, you can use a shell script such as:

```
for ((i = 4; i < 104; i++))
do eval "exec $i> >(programY > out.$i)"
done

programX -d 4 -n 100 &   # Tell programX to write on file descriptors 4 to 103.

# Optionally
for ((i = 4; i < 104; i++))
do eval "exec $i>&-"
done

wait
```

The `wait` command waits for all child processes to terminate before continuing.  AFAICT, that does not include waiting for any of the processes in the 'process substitutions'.

The `eval` operation is necessary to avoid writing out 100 times the 'same' code.  The `for ((...))` loop is a `bash` equivalent of the C `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks - the latter is pretty much what I do at the moment. I worry about the bash caveat concerning file descriptors - this applies in both scenarios you describe. And I wonder whether this is in general a sane approach to the problem.

Comment: The program to launch the processes cannot run foul of bash's internal file descriptor usage.  Any such file descriptors are marked 'close-on-exec', so that they are not inherited by any of bash's child processes.  (I have a trivial program, `fd`, that prints out `o` or `-` for each open or closed file descriptor (4 lines of 64 characters) and it does not detect any `bash`-opened file descriptors; I used it to validate the code in the answer.)  I don't think you'll have any problems even with bash's internal descriptors if your cover script exits soon after programX completes.